# Object roll-back, copy-on-write, versioned proxy etc in Python

Tags: python, metaprogramming, rollback, magic-methods, copy-on-write

**Premise**: Given a Python object `obj`, I want to pass it along to some random function, and, when the function is done, I need the option to reset `obj` to it's original state. Additionally, no actual changes can be made to the `obj` as other code may still want to access it's original state.

---

The optimal solution should be quick in the common case where a large `obj` is only slightly modified. Performance for the uncommon case where an `obj` needs to be rolled back is less important.

Those requirements are orthogonal to the brute force solution of simply copying the object: It would be ridiculously slow in the common case, and super fast for the uncommon roll-back.

The solution should generally allow the code working on the object to treat it as a normal object. This includes assigning all sorts of attributes to it, including custom classes. Obviously, the solution needs to take into consideration the entire object tree. Some concessions may be needed. Examples of restrictions I've considered in my solutions so far include requiring non-basic types to all inherit from a special base class, disallowing dicts and lists in exchange for tuples and a custom dict class etc. Major arcana may be acceptable.

I've been working on this for a while, and would love to see if what ideas and suggestions more experienced Python wizards may have.

---

Edit: Fred's answer made me realize a missing requirement: No changes can be made to the original `obj`, as the original state is also valuable.

Comment: Very broad question, you should probably find out what you absolutely *need* instead of just asking what is possible.

Comment: Thats is true. However, if I knew exactly what I needed, I would be long gone implementing it by now :)

Comment: requirements exist because there's a problem to be solved.  What's the problem?  Based on that, a solution -- and requirements -- can be crafted.  To speak hypothetically about all kinds of features is to avoid *solving* a problem.  Provide some context, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've actually implemented two solutions to this question by now, and seeing as there are no other answers, I might as well share one.

The easiest solution is to use **Copy On Demand**. If we have a proxy `P` targeting object `O`: `P` will have a `__getattr__` method so that when `P.x` is attempted, it tries to copy from `O.x`, storing it on `P.x` at the same time. This has the effect that future access of `P.x` will never reach `__getattr__`, and modifications to `P.x` will not affect the original.

There are a bunch of implementation details:

Maintaining a list of attributes that are deleted from `P`; if `P` is merged with `O`, the deleted attributes must be deleted from `O`.

Writing custom deep copying routines for any supported datatypes, such as `dict`, `list`, etc - making sure to replace all objects `O` with a proxy `P` in the copied `dict`, `list`, etc.

Writing `ProxyDict`, `ProxyList` etc if desired.

Making sure proxy chains, that is proxy to a proxy, works. This basically means to avoid side effects when a proxy to a proxy needs to see if an attribute exists.

Implementing methods for merging the proxy downwards into the proxied object, and splitting it entirely, copying in remaining data from the proxied object.

Even so, compared to the complexity of the effect, it is a very easy to understand solution: The proxy simply copies any data that is accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into [Memento](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern) design pattern

[Here's a example for python](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/286132-memento-design-pattern-in-python/)

Comment: That example does not match the Wikipedia article's description.

Comment: I read the wikipedia article and some misc googled articles for the memento pattern, and I cannot come to any other conclusion than that it serializes the part of the class state that needs to be restored. Now, Python is a very dynamic language, and I expressively made a note of wanting to roll-back a dynamic python object - that is one for which you cannot make a catch-all memento (except for copying the entire state). Maybe I am just confused, but that's what you get when you link a pattern instead of actually writing an explanation related to my question.

Comment: @porgarmingduod: "one for which you cannot make a catch-all memento"?  What?  Python is a very dynamic language.  You can capture all aspects of an object's state.  It's in `object.__dict__`.